# Cannot display the table from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

It cannot display the table from database. For each program there is a table, in which some scores are saved. Plus, there is a program table in which `program id` and `program name` are saved. When I selected a program and a year I got the following errors:

> No data found
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\ac_directorPrograms.php on line 61
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\statistics\ac_directorPrograms.php on line 61

Something goes wrong with the `result` from the action code and I guess with the `prog_name` and `program` form the form.

The form:

```
   <?php 
      include 'connect.php'; 
   ?>
    <form name="myform" action="ac_directorPrograms.php" method="POST">

      <b>Programs:<b/>
        <select name="program"> 
        <option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
        <?php
                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT prog_name FROM program");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['prog_name'] . "'>" .    $row['prog_name'] ."</option>";
                }
        ?>  
         </select><br/><br/>

<b>Year:<b/>
<select name="year"> 
<option value="Choose">Please select..</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option> 
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option></select><br/><br/>


<br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">

</form>
</div>
```

the action code

```
      <?php 

        include 'connect.php';

        $year = $_POST['year'];
        $program = $_POST['program']; 
        $years     = array(
            2005,
            2006,
            2007
       );
       $programs = array(
          'bsc computer science',
          'bsc psychology',
          'ba finance',
          'ba marketing',
          'ba management'
       );

       if (in_array($program, $programs) && in_array($year, $years)) {

          $sql = "SELECT a1,a2,a3,l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7,lavg,r1,r2,u1,u2,u3 FROM $program WHERE year=$year";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
      }

      else {
            echo "No data found";
     }
     ?>
        <html>
         <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../statistics/style.css">
         </head>
          <body>

           <div id="container">
            <table id="table" width="900" border="1" cellspacing="1">

             <tbody>
               <tr>
                <td>A1 </td>
                <td>A2 </td>
                <td>A3 </td>
                <td>L1 </td>
                <td>L2 </td>
                <td>L3 </td>
                <td>L4 </td>
                <td>L5 </td>
                <td>L6 </td>
                <td>L7 </td>
                <td>LAVG </td>
                 <td>R1 </td>
                <td>R2 </td>
                <td>U1 </td>
                <td>U2 </td>
               <td>U3 </td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
       <?php
              while($program=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['a1']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['a2']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$pprogram['a3']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$pprogram['l1']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l2']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l3']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l4']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l5']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l6']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['l7']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['lavg']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['r1']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['r2']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['u1']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['u2']."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".$program['u3']."</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";    
               }
            ?>
      </table>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: try to echo sql may be you are able to get inside if condition that is why result is not defined and you are getting the warning. start using mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the action code and after the `include connect.php`, add this...
`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");` and dont forget to replace `my_user`,`my_password`, `my_db` with yours user, password and database name.

Also replace this code `$result = mysql_query($sql);` with this one `$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);`

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue of scope of the variable. You have defined $result inside if condition and using that out side of if. You need to define $result out side of if condition.

Comment: I posted that question from I used the first answer that is why I have the '$result' inside the 'if ' condition [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487723/cannot-display-the-proper-table-in-php